# How to print lines with the specified word in the path?

Tags: bash, awk

Let's say I have file **abc.txt** which contains the following lines:

```
a b c /some/path/123/path/120
a c b /some/path/312/path/098
a p t /some/path/123/path/321
a b c /some/path/098/path/123
```

and **numbers.txt**:

```
123
321
123
098
```

I want to print the whole line which contain "123" only in the **third place** under "*/some/path/123/path*", 
I don't want to print line "*a c b/some/path/312/path*" or 
"*a b c /some/path/098/path/123/*". I want to save all files with the "123" in the third place in the new file.

I tried several methods and the best way seems to be use awk. Here is my example code which is not working correctly:

```
for i in `cat numbers.txt | xargs`
do
cat abc.txt | awk -v i=$i '$4 ~ /i/ {print $0}' > ${i}_number.txt;
done
```

because it's catching also for example "*a b c /some/path/098/path/123/*".

**Example**:

For number "123" I want to save only one line from **abc.txt** in **123_number.txt**:

```
a b c /some/path/123/path/120
```

For number "312" I want to save only one line from **abc.txt** in **312_number.txt**:

```
a c b /some/path/312/path/098
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be accomplished in a single awk call:

```
$ awk -F'/' 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} ($4 in a){f=$4"_number.txt";print >>f;close(f)}' numbers.txt abc.txt
$ cat 098_number.txt 
a b c /some/path/098/path/123
$ cat 123_number.txt 
a b c /some/path/123/path/120
a p t /some/path/123/path/321
```

keep numbers in an array and use it for matching lines, append matching lines to corresponding files.

if your files are huge you may speed up the process using `sort`:

```
sort -t'/' -k4 abc.txt | awk -F'/' 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} ($4 in a){if($4!=p){close(f);f=(p=$4)"_number.txt"};print >>f}' numbers.txt -
```